# SQL Query Intersections

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem using Intersections in SQL:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

I'm using a for loop to generate all queries to intersect and retrieve the desired data.

My problem:

I need to select varC where exists a varA in a list of values AND varB also in a list of values.

Using `WHERE IN varA ('','','','',...'') and varB ('','','','',...'')` the result are not correct because it not restrict all values.

So I'm using `INTERSECT`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < varA.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < varB.Count; j++)
    {
        sqlQuery += @"SELECT DISTINCT varC FROM tblData WHERE varD='XPTO' AND varA='" + varA[i] + "' AND varB='" + varB[j] + "' INTERSECT ";
    }
}   

   sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Remove(sqlQuery.Length - 10, 10); //to remove last INTERSECT
   sqlQuery += " ORDER BY varC ASC";
```

There is any idea how to do it?

It works using a small dataset but if we increase the list of values it crashes even using a high command timeout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?  Your method is possibly not the best approach.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to use the `INTERSECT` operator? It doesn't feel correct to me since it means it will return distinct values that are returned by both the LEFT and the RIGHT query. Can you indeed give an example of the question you want to ask to the database? I'm sure there is a solution for your requirements that do not require an individual query for each combination of `varA` and `varB`.

Comment: Hi, this is an example: http://s11.postimg.org/w61kv1s1f/Screen_Shot_2014_11_10_at_14_49_51.png If the user select A1 and A2 and B01,B02 I will show only varC that contains selected values in column varA and varB.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to generate a query of this form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT varC 
FROM tblData 
WHERE 
    varD='XPTO' 
    AND (
        (varA = "VALUEA1" and varB = "VALUEB1")
     OR (varA = "VALUEA2" and varB = "VALUEB2")
     OR (varA = "VALUEA3" and varB = "VALUEB3")
     OR (varA = "VALUEA4" and varB = "VALUEB4")
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want this:

```
select varc
from tbldata
group by varc
having sum(case when varA in (<list of A values>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when varB in (<list of B values>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a script with temporary table having these three arg columns like this:

```
declare @t table (A nvarchar(max), B nvarchar(max), D nvarchar(max))
insert into @t (A, B, D) values ('valA1', 'valB1', 'valD1')
insert into @t (A, B, D) values ('valA2', 'valB2', 'valD2')
...

select distinct varC 
from tblData D 
inner join @t T on D.A = T.A and D.B = T.B and D.D = T.D
```